# Problem starting development server - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel

I've recently upgraded to Rails 2.3.2 with Ruby 1.8.7. Whenever I start the server like this:

```
cd /myproject
script/server
```

It hangs. After I cancel it the only error information that I see is:

```
^C/Users/timstephenson/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/load_error.rb:32:in `new': Interrupt
```

The error began after upgrading. Looking in the server log in the project logs folder, nothing is written. Also nothing is in the development log.

I'm using Mac OSX 10.5

I updated all the gems and cleaned out old gems. All old items came from and old computer with a PPC chip and Tiger. Before upgrading to 1.8.7 of Ruby and 2.3.2 of Rails, things were working even though ruby seemed to be compiled for PPC instead of i686.

I can use script/console and interact with the models in my project successfully.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Are you using mongrel? If so, try `script/server webrick` and see if that works. I believe this is probably the same issue as http://mongrel.rubyforge.org/ticket/37.

Comment: Also, if you want to use mongrel, I'd suggest using Ruby Enterprise Edition (http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/) Instead of 1.8.7 of MRI, as 1.8.7 does all types of weird things all the time for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app has permission to write to your log folder. If it doesn't, that could be why you're not getting any log entries.

As a last-ditch solution, try making a new rails app, re-scaffolding your database, then moving your app folder over to the new app. This will mean that your Rails code is compatible with your installed versions of Rails and Ruby, which your older code might not be.

You'll also need to copy over any other code that you've written that isn't in your app folder.

Be warned: this is really a last resort.